# Execute Two Database Calls (with Two DbContexts) Simultaneously

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, ef-core-2.2

I need to get results from two different `DbContext` (which target two different schemas of an Oracle database) to populate a page.  I to want to execute both database queries (*read only, no write operations*) simultaneously and return the results when they're both done.  Trouble is, I'm a serial dude in a parallel world, and I don't know jack about `Async`/`Await`/`TPL` etc…

I have a controller `Action` that looks basically like this:

```
public Task<IActionResult> Foo(MyViewModel vm)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Task.Run(()=> (IActionResult)View(vm));

  var filter = new FilterObject(vm);
  var firstTask = _firstContext.FilterItems(filter); // returns Task<IQueryable<Items>>
  var secondTask = _secondContext.FilterItems(filter); // returns Task<IQueryable<Items>> 

  vm.Result.Clear();
  vm.Results.AddRange(firstTask.Result);
  vm.Results.AddRange(secondTask.Result);

  return Task.Run(()=> (IActionResult)View("Index", vm));
}
```

My `DbContext` calls the filter to do its job:

```
public class FirstContext : DbContext
{
  public DbQuery<Items> Items{get;set;}

  public Task<IQueryable<Items>> FilterItems(FilterObject filter)
  {
     filter.ApplyTo(Items.AsQueryable());
  }
}
```

... and my FilterObject modifies the IQueryable:

```
public class FilterObject
{
  public Task<IQueryable<Items>> ApplyTo(IQueryable<Items> items)
  {
    return Task.Run(()=> items
      .Where(item => item.Property1.Contains(this.Property1))
      .Where(item => item.Other == this.OtherString)
       // more Where clauses ad nauseum; you get the idea
  }
}
```

Am I doing this anywhere close to right?  As I understand it, the call to the database won't actually execute until the `AddRange` method, because the `Task.Result` is an `IQueryable` - so that seems wrong to me: the `AddRange()` methods will execute synchronously, not asynchronously, right?  All I've done is build two queries, not execute them.  I'm guessing that I need to return a `List<Item>` from the DbContext, which will cause each query to actually execute... but is that the only change I need to make so that these calls happen at the same time, without blocking each other?

As always, any guidance is immensely appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run` for I/O work? `async/await` is your friend here.

Comment: You need to learn about EF Core and async/await *before* you try to create your own dynamic filtering mechanism. An IQueryable is just the query, so there's no reason to run it in the background. If you check the ASP.NET Core, EF Core tutorials you'll see the code is simple and the *only* difference between an async and synchronous action is the `ToListAsync()` vs `ToList` calls. It's `ToListAsync() or `ToList() that actually execute the query

Comment: You definitely want to wrap a using statement around both contexts unless they're injected.

Comment: @user10728126 [You don't need to call `Dispose()` on `DbContext`](https://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext/). You can do it if you want to, but it's not important.

Comment: @Gabriel Luci How does it get disposed if you're not using a container?

Comment: @user10728126 Read the article :) it just doesn't need to be disposed. It'll close the connection when it's not needed, whether you dispose or not.

Comment: @KennethK I tried to make it clear I do not know what I'm doing.  :-)

Comment: @user10728126 they are injected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Drop all your `Task` work from the IQueryables you have. That's one layer too much. Keep it simple. You have a query. That will return an `IQueryable<>`. Then you use `ToListAsync` to get the results asynchronously:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(MyViewModel vm)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return View(vm);

  var filter = new FilterObject(vm);
  var firstTask = _firstContext.YourQueryable.ToListAsync();
  var secondTask = _secondContext.YourQueryable.ToListAsync();    

  var firstResult = await firstTask;
  var secondResult = await secondTask;

  vm.Result.Clear();
  vm.Results.AddRange(firstResult);
  vm.Results.AddRange(secondResult);

  return View("Index", vm);
}
```

Comment: When I call `await firstTask` am I not blocking until the result is returned?

Comment: You do, but since the other task is already started, they run in parallel. The second one will execute while you wait on the first one. That's why the task creation comes first and waiting on them second.

Answer (score 2):

`Task.Run` will move the task into another thread, which isn't really necessary. Use `async` and `await`, which will run everything on the same thread, but will allow other work to be done on the same thread while waiting for the results. For example, after firing the first query, it can start the second query while waiting for the first to finish.

It seems like `FilterItems` and `ApplyTo` are just modifying the query, and not actually executing the result, so I don't see why they need to return a `Task` at all. You can use [`ToListAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.tolistasync) to actually execute the query, after the query has been built.

For example:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Foo(MyViewModel vm)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid) return Task.Run(()=> (IActionResult)View(vm));

  var filter = new FilterObject(vm);

  //This will execute the queries
  var firstTask = _firstContext.FilterItems(filter).ToListAsync();
  var secondTask = _secondContext.FilterItems(filter).ToListAsync();

  vm.Result.Clear();
  vm.Results.AddRange(await firstTask); //add the first set when they're available
  vm.Results.AddRange(await secondTask); //add the second set when they're available

  return View("Index", vm);
}
```

You didn't have a `return` in `FilterItems`, but I assumed it should be there:

```
public class FirstContext : DbContext
{
  public DbQuery<Items> Items{get;set;}

  public IQueryable<Items> FilterItems(FilterObject filter)
  {
     return filter.ApplyTo(Items.AsQueryable());
  }
}
```

```
public class FilterObject
{
  public IQueryable<Items> ApplyTo(IQueryable<Items> items)
  {
    return items
      .Where(item => item.Property1.Contains(this.Property1))
      .Where(item => item.Other == this.OtherString)
       // more Where clauses ad nauseum; you get the idea
  }
}
```